# ObservableCollection and CollectionChanged event as WCF datacontract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I use DataContract with ObservableCollection:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Terms.MyNamespace)]
public class MyContract 
{
internal MyContract ()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
[DataMember]
private ObservableCollection<string> list;

[XmlArray("list")]
        public ObservableCollection<string> List
        {
            get
            {
                return list;
            }
            set
            {
                list = value;
                list.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("It is never happens!! Why?"); 
                    };
            }
        }
...
```

So, when I work with my collection like this.

```
MyContract contract = new MyContract();
contract.List.Add("some");
```

Item was been added but CollectionChanged event not fired.

Why?

Comment: WCF data contract ought **not** to contain any logic / code since that code **cannot** be serialized across the communications link from server to client and back. WCF is a **message-passing** system - all that goes from client to server and back are **serialized XML messages** and those cannot contain behavior/logic/code.

Comment: Ok, is it poosible anything to do in this situation? I need mark my contract(for example set additionally boolean datamember field to true) when in client collection was changed. Set this field implicitly in code isn't possible...

Comment: Those data contracts on the client-side will be *partial* classes - you can extend those to handle the detection of change, and setting of a property inside the data contract. Do you need that flag only on the client?? Or do you need to transfer that back to the server at some point??

Comment: I need to transer this flag back to the server. And the problem is when I extend my contract it doesent work fot Observable colletion. So if I set my flag in set section of property - it works fine, but if I work with obserablese collection throw Add, Insert and Remove methods I couldn't detect that collection was changed. Because OnCollectionChanged event doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you don't serialize `List` while serialize `list`. So, during deserialization it won't call setter of list, therefore won't subscribe to event. In your case you can simply mark `List` with `DataMemberAttribute` instead of `list`, e.g.:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyContract
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> list;

    internal MyContract()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<string> List
    {
        get
        {
            return list;
        }
        private set
        {
            list = value;
            list.CollectionChanged += 
               (s, e) => 
                   Console.WriteLine("It is never happens!! Why? - Are you sure?!");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = new MyContract();

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyContract));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var result = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as MyContract;

    result.List.Add("a");
}
```

In this case event will fire.